# Extracting data from Chinese language document

Tags: machine-learning, ocr, rpa, abbyy, workfusion

Does workfusion have support for extracting data from Chinese language document by using OCR and Machine learning. Please advice.

Regards,
Sunil Prabakar C

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a generic answer: Yes, Chinese language is supported.

A bit more details:

- WorkFusion OCR module supports about 200 languages (including Chinese Simplified and and Chinese Traditional)
- WorkFusion ML module is language agnostic. Training set size may be required to be of a bigger size for less common languages, as well as configuration may need to include language specific features for better results.
- WorkFusion RPA module is language agnostic. It can interact with applications with pretty much any language of the user interface. More technically precise: it’s character encoding-agnostic. More than 100 character encodings supported including all wide used (different versions of Unicode/UTF, ISO, ASCII, IBM, windows, many more).